# Issue with nginx config using docker

Tags: docker, nginx

I'm start doing a little test using docker in order to set up my own server and I have a little bit issues.

I use the `nginx-fpm` image which have most of the services I need to set up my server.

This is my `Dockerfile` I did in order to set up a basic server. I built it perfectly without any issues and named it as `nginx-custom-server`.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM "richarvey/nginx-php-fpm"

ADD /conf/simple-project.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/simple-project.conf

RUN mkdir /srv/www/
RUN mkdir /LOGS/
RUN ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/simple-project.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/simple-project.conf
RUN rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.conf

CMD ["/start.sh"]
```

I ran it using the following command via terminal.

```
docker run --name=server-stack -v /home/ismael/Documentos/docker-nginx/code:/srv/www -v /home/ismael/Documentos/docker-nginx/logs:/LOGS -p 80:80 -d nginx-custom-server:stack
```

In `/srv/www` folder I have a simple hello world `php`. I want make changes in my code on my local machine and sync it with docker container using the shared folder `code`.

The nginx logs are empty so I don't know what is wrong. I set up logs in my conf but nginx didn't create them so I think there is a problem with the general nginx conf I guess.

Here is the conf I'm using for my hello world. Also I mapped this server name in the hosts of the host machine.

**simple-project.conf**

```
server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    server_name simple-project.olive.com;
    root /srv/www/simple-project/;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        # the ubuntu default
        fastcgi_pass   /var/run/php-fpm.sock:9000;

        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_param APPLICATION_ENV int;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        return 404;
    }

    error_log /LOGS/custom_error.log;
    access_log /LOGS/custom_access.log;
}
```

EDIT : Error when I tried to access to the server inside docker's container.

> bash-4.4# wget localhost:80 > /tmp/output.html
>   --2019-03-27 12:33:11--  http://localhost/ Resolving localhost... 127.0.0.1, ::1 Connecting to localhost|127.0.0.1|:80... failed: Connection refused. Connecting to localhost|::1|:80... failed: Address
>   not available. Retrying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can tell, there are two reasons why you can't access the server.

The first is that you don't forward any ports from the container to the host. You should include the `-p 80:80` argument to your `docker run` command.

The second is that you're attempting to listen on what I assume to be the IP of the container itself, which is not static (by default). In the nginx config, you should replace `listen 172.17.0.2:80;` with `listen 0.0.0.0:80;`.

With these two modifications in place, you should be able to access your server.

A different approach (but not recommended) would be to start the container in with the `--network=host` parameter. This way, the host's network is actually visible from within the container. In this scenario, you would only need to set the nginx config to listen on a valid address.

However, if the problem persists, a good approach would be to run `docker exec -it {$container_id} bash` when the container is running and see if you can access the server from within the container itself. This would mean that the server is running correctly but from other reasons, the port is not being correctly forwarded to the host.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I have a new problem . I updated the answer so thanks in advance.

Comment: The error usually occurs when you have another service on localhost listening on port 80. That can possibly reffer to another nginx server listening on 80? One way to find out is to run sudo netstat -tlnp | grep 80 (on unix) and see which is the culprit.

Comment: Yea it's true, I had another container with the previous nginx configuration. I set up like you told in your answer but I can't still access to the server. I'm inside the container trying to figure out what is going on. I tried this `wget 172.17.0.2:80 > /tmp/output.html` but I got Connection refused from inside the container.

Comment: Have you tried running `wget localhost:80` from inside the container? Since server is on 0.0.0.0, you will surely not receive any answer from 172.17.0.2 from _within_ the container.

Comment: I updated the question, but also it gaves me a connection refused error.

Comment: Can you set the nginx conf to listen on `127.0.0.1:80` and retry the above command?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190770/discussion-between-bogsan-and-ismael-moral).